# windowsauthentication_onauthenticate function is not fired in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am migrating application from asp.net 2.0 to asp.net 4.5 and I am having problem with the windowsauthentication_onauthenticate function. It is not getting fired when the application runs?

In the Global.asax, I have following function:

```
Protected Sub WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs)

    If Not (e.Identity Is Nothing) AndAlso e.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then

.....
.....

    End If

End Sub
```

I tried couple of things present in [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis) link 
(point-10 is the similar to mine but still I am getting error)

Can any one please suggest me, how can i proceed further on this?

Comment: I think it has been moved in 4.5 version from `Global.asax`!!

Comment: Yup global.asax will be moved to 4.5 .... So do I need to remove the method windowsauthentication-onauthenticate function and can try Ihttpmodule?

Comment: Where you can move am not sure but yes it will not be there in `global.asax`